# Fdist and top 10 function words

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

I have to write a script that will give me all content words in decending order of frequency.
I need the 10 most frequent content words, I thus not only need to make a list of the 10 most frequent words of my corpus, I will also need to filter out any content words (and, or, any punctuation...).
What I have so far is the following

```
fileids=corpus.fileids ()
text=corpus.words(fileids)
wlist=[]
ftable=nltk.FreqDist (text)
wlist.append(ftable.keys () )
```

This gives me a very neat list of all words in decending order of frequency, but how do I filter the function words out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to filter out a set of words (stopwords). Taking the [core idea from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486337/stop-words-using-nltk-in-python):

You need to introduce a couple of lines into your code:
Just after

```
fileids=corpus.fileids ()
text=corpus.words(fileids)
```

**Add the following lines**: Create a list of stopwords and filter them out from your text

```
#get a list of the stopwords
stp = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')

#from your text of words, keep only the ones NOT in stp
filtered_text = [w for w in text if not w in stp]
```

Now, continue as you would

```
wlist=[]
ftable=nltk.FreqDist (filtered_text)
wlist.append(ftable.keys () )
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why, I didn't know NLTK had a built in list of stopwords, thanks a million

Comment: Yes, NLTK is a fantastic resource, and I am always discovering new treasures in it.