# Getting rid of stop words and document tokenization using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, stop-words

I’m having difficulty eliminating and tokenizing a .text file using `nltk`. I keep getting the following `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'`.

I just can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong, although it’s my first time of doing something like this. Below are my lines of code.I’ll appreciate any suggestions, thanks

```py
    import nltk
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    s = open("C:\zircon\sinbo1.txt").read()
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    def cleanupDoc(s):
            stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
        cleanup = [token.lower()for token in tokens.lower() not in stopset and  len(token)>2]
        return cleanup
    cleanupDoc(s)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `stopwords` lists from NLTK, see [How to remove stop words using nltk or python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486337/how-to-remove-stop-words-using-nltk-or-python).

And most probably you would also like to strip off punctuation, you can use `string.punctuation`, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> import string
>>> sent = "this is a foo bar, bar black sheep."
>>> stop = set(stopwords.words('english') + list(string.punctuation))
>>> [i for i in word_tokenize(sent.lower()) if i not in stop]
['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'black', 'sheep']
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it seems like you're trying to convert a list, not a string, to lowercase. Your `tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s)` is probably not returning what you expect (which seems to be a string).

It would be helpful to know what format your `sinbo.txt` file is in.

A few syntax issues:

1. Import should be in lowercase: `import nltk`
2. The line `s = open("C:\zircon\sinbo1.txt").read()` is reading the whole file in, not a single line at a time. This may be problematic because word_tokenize works [on a single sentence](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html), not any sequence of tokens. This current line assumes that your `sinbo.txt` file contains a single sentence. If it doesn't, you may want to either (a) use a for loop on the file instead of using read() or (b) use punct_tokenizer on a whole bunch of sentences divided by punctuation.
3. The first line of your `cleanupDoc` function is not properly indented. your function should look like this (even if the functions within it change).

   ```
   import nltk
   from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
   def cleanupDoc(s):
    stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    cleanup = [token.lower() for token in tokens if token.lower() not in stopset and  len(token)>2]
    return cleanup
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
def cleanupDoc(s):
     stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
     tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
     cleanup = " ".join(filter(lambda word: word not in stopset, s.split()))
     return cleanup
s = "I am going to disco and bar tonight"
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
x = cleanupDoc(s)
print x
```

This code can help in solving the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case the error is in 
`cleanup = [token.lower()for token in tokens.lower() not in stopset and  len(token)>2]`

tokens is a list, so you cannot do tokens.lower() operation on a list. So, another way of writing the above code would be,

```
cleanup = [token.lower()for token in tokens if token.lower() not in stopset and  len(token)>2]
```

I hope this helps.