# Error when extract noun-phrases from the training corpus and remove stop words using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

I am new to both, python and NLTK. I have to extract noun phrase from the corpus and then remove the stop words by using NLTK. I already do my coding but still have error. Can anyone help me to fix this problem? Or please also recommend if there is any better solution. Thank you

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

docid='19509'
title='Example noun-phrase and stop words'
print('Document id:'),docid
print('Title:'),title

#list noun phrase
content='This is a sample sentence, showing off the stop words filtration.'
is_noun = lambda pos: pos[:2] == 'NN'
tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(content)
nouns = [word for (word,pos) in nltk.pos_tag(tokenized) if is_noun(pos)]
print('All Noun Phrase:'),nouns

#remove stop words
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

example_words = word_tokenize(nouns)
filtered_sentence = []

for w in example_words:
  if w not in stop_words:
     filtered_sentence.append(w)

print('Without stop words:'),filtered_sentence
```

And I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\NLP\stop_word.py", line 20, in <module>
  example_words = word_tokenize(nouns)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 109,in 
 word_tokenize
  return [token for sent in sent_tokenize(text, language)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 94, in 
 sent_tokenize
  return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1237, in 
 tokenize
  return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1285, in 
 sentences_from_text
  return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text,realign_boundaries)]
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1276, in 
 span_tokenize
  return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1316, in 
 _realign_boundaries
  for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 310, in 
 _pair_iter
  prev = next(it)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1289, in 
 _slices_from_text
  for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: Can you explain what is exactly the error? Which part is not working?

Comment: too many error and I can't understand it. I already attach the error above @christinabo

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486337/how-to-remove-stop-words-using-nltk-or-python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because the function `word_tokenize` is expecting a string as an argument and you give a list of strings.
As far as I understand what you are trying to achieve, you do not need tokenize at this point. Until the `print('All Noun Phrase:'),nouns`, you have all the nouns of your sentence. To remove the stopwords, you can use:

```
### remove stop words ###
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
# find the nouns that are not in the stopwords
nouns_without_stopwords = [noun for noun in nouns if noun not in stop_words]
# your sentence is now clear
print('Without stop words:',nouns_without_stopwords)
```

Of course, in this case you have the same result with nouns, because none of the nouns was a stopword.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yeah its work..Thanks a lot for helping me @christinabo