# How to create meaningful column value pair lists from a string?

Tags: python, string, nlp, semantics

I am trying to categorize columns and values (column=value) meaningfully from an input string using Python dictionaries.

```
input_string = "the status is processing and product subtypes are HL year 30 ARM and applicant name is Ryan"
```

I have created dictionaries of key value pairs. In the first scenario, the *key* is the column name. The *value* represents the lowest index of key found in `input_string`.

Here is the dictionary of column names:

```
 dict_columns = {'status': 4, 'product subtypes': 29, 'applicant name': 69}
```

In the above dictionary, `'status'` has the lowest index of `4` in the `input_string`.

Similarly, here is the dictionary of values:

```
dict_values = {'processing': 14, 'hl': 50, 'year': 53, '30': 58, 'arm': 61, 'ryan': 87}
```

**The question is:**

**How to get the expected ouput as:**

```
list_parsed_values = ['processing', 'hl year 30 arm', 'ryan']
```

**and the (optional) corresponding list of columns as:**

```
list_parsed_columns = ['status', 'product subtypes', 'applicant name']
```

**How to clearly distinguish the values in a list?**

Comment: working on raw data (unstructed), I suggest you to use `regex` here

Comment: please, add more examples of input and desired output

Comment: An idea: `re.split` with `r'\b(?:status|product subtypes|applicant name)\b'`,  and [remove all stopwords from the items received](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486337/how-to-remove-stop-words-using-nltk-or-python). Discard empty elements. To know which type of information it is, you might split with the same pattern as above but remove `?:`. Then you could check each odd column for value and even column for key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following approach:

- Build the regex to remove irrelevant words from the results based on the English nltk stopword list
- Build the regex to split the text with using the `dict_columns` keys
- After splitting, zip the resulting list into a tuple list
- Remove the irrelevant words from the values and strip the whitespace

Here is the code I have come so far:

```
import nltk, re
s = "the status is processing and product subtypes are HL year 30 ARM and applicant name is Ryan"
dict_columns = {'status': 4, 'product subtypes': 29, 'applicant name': 69}
dict_values = {'processing': 14, 'hl': 50, 'year': 53, '30': 58, 'arm': 61, 'ryan': 87}
# Build the regex to remove irrelevant words from the results
rx_stopwords = r"\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join([x for x in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("English")]))
# Build the regex to split the text with using the dict_columns keys
rx_split = r"\b({})\b".format("|".join([x for x in dict_columns]))
chunks = re.split(rx_split, s)
# After splitting, zip the resulting list into a tuple list
it = iter(chunks[1:])
lst = list(zip(it, it))
# Remove the irrelevant words from the values and trim them (this can be further enhanced
res = [(x, re.sub(rx_stopwords, "", y).strip()) for x, y in lst]
# =>
#   [('status', 'processing'), ('product subtypes', 'HL year 30 ARM'), ('applicant name', 'Ryan')]
# It can be cast to a dictionary
dict(res)
# => 
#   {'product subtypes': 'HL year 30 ARM', 'status': 'processing', 'applicant name': 'Ryan'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciated your help.
It is working fine now.