# How do I parse a sentence using regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse a sentence like:
"Alice is a boy." into ['Alice', 'boy'] and
and "An elephant is a mammal." into ['elephant', 'mammal']. Meaning I need to split the string by 'is' while also remove 'a/an'.
Is there an elegant way to do it?

Comment: Can you post your attempt at the code?

Comment: What is the format of the sentence?

Comment: Sounds like you need to [remove stopwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486337/how-to-remove-stop-words-using-nltk-or-python) and get the rest by simple splitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insists on using a regex, you can do it like this by using `re.search`:

```
print(re.search('(\w+) is [a|an]? (\w+)',"Alice is a boy.").groups())
# output: ('Alice', 'boy')

print(re.search('(\w+) is [a|an]? (\w+)',"An elephant is a mammal.").groups())
# output: ('elephant', 'mammal')
# apply list() if you want it as a list
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not make us of regex, but is one way of doing things:

```
s = 'Alice is a boy'
s = s.split() # each word becomes an entry in a list
s = [word for word in s if word != 'a' and word !='an' and word !='is']
```

The main downside to this is that you would need to list out every word you want to exclude in the list comprehension.

Comment: What about the example `An elephant is a mammal.`? Also, you forgot the full-stop.

Comment: Simpler is `word for word in s if not word in {'a', 'an', 'is'}`

Comment: That's true, this method does not account for the full stop, oops. One could account for that using the `translate` method in the string package.