# Why "is" and "to" are removed by my regular expression in NLTK RegexpTokenizer()?

Tags: regex, nltk, tokenize

I want to tokenize

```
s = ("mary went to garden. where is mary? "
     "mary is carrying apple and milk. "
     "what mary is carrying? apple,milk")
```

into

```
['mary', 'went', 'to', 'garden', '.', 
 'where', 'is', 'mary', '?', 
 'mary', 'is', 'carrying', 'apple', 'and', 'milk', '.', 
 'what', 'mary', 'is', 'carrying', '?', 'apple,milk']
```

Please note that I want to keep `'apple,milk'` as one word.

My code is:

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('\w+[\]|\w+[\,]\w+|\.|\?')
s = "mary went to garden. where is mary? mary is carrying apple and milk. what mary is carrying? apple,milk"
tokenizer.tokenize(s)
```

the result is:

```
['mary', 'went', 'garden', '.', 
 'where', 'mary', '?', 
 'mary', 'carrying', 'apple', 'and', 'milk', '.', 
 'what', 'mary', 'carrying', '?', 'apple,milk']
```

However, `'is'` and `'to'` are missing. How to keep them?

Comment: Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486337/how-to-remove-stop-words-using-nltk-or-python and  https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/ail12t/1

Answer (score 1):

Your regex pattern simply does not capture the missing words.

You could see this whit a regex tool or using `RegexpTokenizer('\w+[\]|\w+[\,]\w+|\.|\?', True)` with an additional parameter to show gaps instead of tokens ([doc](https://kite.com/docs/python;nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer)).

Update:
Here is a pattern that finds all the tokens as specified by you:

```
\w+[\,]\w+|\w+|\.|\?
```

Remarks: When using regex alternatives it can be important to sort them by length (usually from longest to shortest). The `[\]` does not make sense to me and is syntactically not correct.

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/D2yEAS/2)

Answer (score 1):

The `RegexpTokenizer` simply does a `re.findall` function given the input regex, from https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/regexp.py#L78

```
 def tokenize(self, text):
        self._check_regexp()
        # If our regexp matches gaps, use re.split:
        if self._gaps:
            if self._discard_empty:
                return [tok for tok in self._regexp.split(text) if tok]
            else:
                return self._regexp.split(text)

        # If our regexp matches tokens, use re.findall:
        else:
            return self._regexp.findall(text)
```

Essentially, you're doing:

```
>>> import re
>>> rg = re.compile(r'\w+[\]|\w+[\,]\w+|\.|\?')
>>> sent = "mary went to garden. where is mary? mary is carrying apple and milk. what mary is carrying? apple,milk" 
>>> rg.findall(sent)
['mary', 'went', 'garden', '.', 'where', 'mary', '?', 'mary', 'carrying', 'apple', 'and', 'milk', '.', 'what', 'mary', 'carrying', '?', 'apple,milk']
```

Looking at the explanation of the regex `\w+[\]|\w+[\,]\w+|\.|\?`: https://regex101.com/r/ail12t/1/

The regex has 3 alternatives:

- `\w+[\]|\w+[\,]\w+`:

  - First part `\w+` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]) unlimited times
  - Second part `[\]|\w+[\,]`, is matches any word character within the `\w+` range and also `]`, `|`, `[` or `,` characters.
  - Thirst part `\w+` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]) unlimited times
- `\.`:Fnd the `.` symbol and match it
- `\?`: : TFind the `?` symbol and match it

The reason why two character words gets "gobbled" up is because the multiple `w+w+w+` in the first alternative of the `\w+[\]|\w+[\,]\w+` regex. That means that the regex only catches/finds all the words that has a minimum of >=3 characters.

---

Actually, I think the regex can be further simplified and you can easily break it down into small units and piece them up.

With `\w+`, it will simply match all words and excludes punctuations:

```
>>> rg = re.compile(r'\w+')
>>> sent = "mary went to garden. where is mary? mary is carrying apple and milk. what mary is carrying? apple,milk" 
>>> rg.findall(sent)
['mary', 'went', 'to', 'garden', 'where', 'is', 'mary', 'mary', 'is', 'carrying', 'apple', 'and', 'milk', 'what', 'mary', 'is', 'carrying', 'apple', 'milk']
```

Then to catch the punctuations `[[\]\,\-\|\.]`, simply add them as alternatives separated by `|`, i.e.

```
>>> rg = re.compile(r'\w+|[[\]\,\-\|\.]')
>>> rg.findall(sent)
['mary', 'went', 'to', 'garden', '.', 'where', 'is', 'mary', 'mary', 'is', 'carrying', 'apple', 'and', 'milk', '.', 'what', 'mary', 'is', 'carrying', 'apple', ',', 'milk']
```