# Python Collections.counter and excluding stuff from JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a visualization of frequently used words between '`my`' and '`my gf`' on Facebook. I downloaded all messages directly from FB in a JSON file and I got the counter working

BUT:

- Counter also counts element names from JSON like "`sender_name`" or timestamps which are `13` digit numbers
- The JSON file is lacking **UTF encoding** - I have strings like `\u00c5`, `\u0082a`, `\u00c5`, `\u0082a` hardcoded into the words

How do I exclude short meaningless words like '`you, I, a, but`' etc?

For the first problem I tried creating a dictionary of words to exclude but I have no idea how to even approach excluding them. Also, the problem is with deleting the timestamp numbers because they are not constant.

For the second problem I tried just opening the file in a word editor and replacing the symbol codes but it crashes every time because of the size of the file (more than 1,5 million lines).

Here's the **code** that I used to print most frequent words:

```
import re
import collections
import json

file = open('message.json', encoding="utf8")
a = file.read()

words = re.findall(r'\w+', a)

most_common = collections.Counter(map(str.lower, words)).most_common(50)
print(most_common)
```

And JSON file structure looks like this:

```
{
      "sender_name": "xxxxxx",
      "timestamp_ms": 1540327935616,
      "content": "Podobaj\u00c4\u0085 ci si\u00c4\u0099",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using `findall` over the whole file, do something like this:

```
import re
import collections
import json


def words(s):
    return re.findall('\w+', s, re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE)

file = open('message.json', encoding="utf8")
data = json.load(file)

counts = collections.Counter((w.lower() for e in data for w in words(e.get('content', ''))))
most_common = counts.most_common(50)
print(most_common)
```

**Output**

```
[('siä', 1), ('ci', 1), ('podobajä', 1)]
```

The output is for a file with the following content (a list of JSON objects):

```
[{
      "sender_name": "xxxxxx",
      "timestamp_ms": 1540327935616,
      "content": "Podobaj\u00c4\u0085 ci si\u00c4\u0099",
      "type": "Generic"
}]
```

**Explanation**

With `json.load` load the content of the file as a list of dictionaries `data`, then iterate over the elements of the dictionary and count the words of the `'content'` field using the function `words` and `Counter`

**Further**

1. For removing words such as I, a and but see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486337/how-to-remove-stop-words-using-nltk-or-python)

**UPDATE**

Given the format of the file you need to alter the line: `data = json.load(file)` to `data = json.load(file)["messages"]`, for the following content:

```
{
  "participants":[],
  "messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "xxxxxx",
      "timestamp_ms": 1540327935616,
      "content": "Podobaj\u00c4\u0085 ci si\u00c4\u0099",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "aaa",
      "timestamp_ms": 1540329382942,
      "content": "aaa",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "aaa",
      "timestamp_ms": 1540329262248,
      "content": "aaa",
      "type": "Generic"
    }
  ]
}
```

The **output** is:

```
[('aaa', 2), ('siä', 1), ('podobajä', 1), ('ci', 1)]
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: counts = collections.Counter((w.lower() for e in data for w in words(e.get('content', ''))))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Is the JSON a list of only JSON objects or does the list include strings also?

Comment: Sadly I can't answer that question with my current knowledge yet. It starts like this and just goes on till the last message:

{
  "participants": [
    {
      "name": "aaa"
    },
    {
      "name": "aaa"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "aaa",
      "timestamp_ms": 1540329382942,
      "content": "aaa",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "aaa",
      "timestamp_ms": 1540329262248,
      "content": "aaa",
      "type": "Generic"
    },

Comment: @MarsinKa Updated the answer!

Comment: Damn, works like a charm! So if I want to read a specific element from JSON I can just name it in square brackets when loading the file?

Comment: @MarsinKa json.load transforms the input into a dictionary, so you can access any key using square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the json as a dictionary and inspecting types? You can also look for unwanted words after the fact and remove them.

```
import json
from collections import Counter

def get_words(string):
    return [word.lower() for word in string.split() if word.lower()]

def count_words(json_item):
    if isinstance(json_item, dict):
        for key, value in json_item.items():
            return count_words(key) + count_words(value)
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        return get_words(value)
    elif isinstance(value, list):
        return [word for string in value for word in count_words(string)]
    else:
        return []

with open('message.json', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    json_input = json.load(f)
counter = Counter(count_words(json_input))
result = { key: value for key, value in counter.items() if key not in UNWANTED_WORDS}
```