# Removing single letter stopwords without removing the letter from words containing it

Tags: python, stop-words

I am trying to remove stopwords from my text.

I have tried using the code below.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
sw = stopwords.words("english")
my_text='I love coding'
my_text=re.sub("|".join(sw),"",my_text)
print(my_text)
```

Expected result: `love coding`.
Actual result:   `I l cng` (since 'o' and 've' are both found in the stopwords list "sw").

How can I get the expected result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486337/how-to-remove-stop-words-using-nltk-or-python possible duplication...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the sentence to words before removing the stop words and then run

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
sentence = 'I love coding'
print([i for i in sentence.lower().split() if i not in stop])
>>> ['love', 'coding']
print(" ".join([i for i in sentence.lower().split() if i not in stop]))
>>> "love coding"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace words, not characrters:

```
from itertools import filterfalse
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
sw = stopwords.words("english")
my_text = 'I love coding'
my_words = my_text.split() # naive split to words
no_stopwords = ' '.join(filterfalse(sw.__contains__, my_words))
```

You should also worry about splitting sentences, case sensitivity, etc.

There are libraries to do this properly since this is a common, non-trivial, problem.