# Extract most common words cleaned as WordCloud?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I want to extract the most common words in a DataFrame with `[Word, Count]` as columns.

The results should be similar to the one presented by `WordCloud`, as you can see only relevant words are considered. So no stopwords, multiple words for item, and capitalization maintained.

[WordCloud Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW78m.jpg)

I've tried using Counter but the result consider only single word and stopwords are still presents.

```
x = Counter(' '.join(df['name']).split()).most_common(20)
pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['word', 'count'])

    word    count
0   in      8875
1   Private 3224
2   Room    2925
3   to      2645
4   room    2512
5   Bedroom 2404
6   Cozy    2324
7   2       2255
8   Brooklyn    2099
9   Apartment   2075
10  &       1966
12  Manhattan   1824
11  1       1885
13  with    1815
14  and     1714
15  of      1703
16  the     1700
17  Studio  1638
18  bedroom 1615
19  -       1567
```

Comment: Like a Top 10?..

Comment: you can use `ntlk` to remove stopwords, for example with something like in this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/46977475/10035985